# Nginx not redirecting to expected location

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have read a number of articles ([primarily this](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0)) but I am still failing to understand why my url is not redirected correctly.

I have a virtual on 192.168.1.4 running Ubuntu-Server. I have installed nginx and I can see the nginx welcome page.

All of my traffic from my router's port 80 is successfully redirected to 192.168.1.4.

I have these websites:

```
Site1 - 192.168.1.3:9810 (IIS) - www.mydomain1.com
192.168.1.1
    Site2 - 192.168.1.1:8080 (admin page for my server) www.mydomain2.com
    Site3 - 192.168.1.1:81 (a wordpress site) www.mydomain3.com
```

Now with all three domains, I am hitting the nginx welcome page, so I know that the problem is with my configuration, which is shown below:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name mydomain1.com; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.3:9810;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain2.com; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:8080;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain3.com; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:81;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:8080;

    }
}
```

What is it that I've done wrong? I tested each one individually by doing something like:

```
URL: 192.168.1.4:80/ --redirects--> 192.168.1.3:9810
```

And it redirects correctly

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to check it is using the correct configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith `the config file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok` followed by `config file /../nginx.conf test is successful`.I see in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` this line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` so should be ok

Comment: Is there a default `server` block in the config file?

Comment: @RichardSmith I've added in my default server config in my post (I've also tried toggling Ipv6 to no avail)

Answer (score 0):

This looks partly like a default server issue. Do you have a default_server directive anywhere? Or any other server defined that uses the default Nginx page?

What I think is happening is Nginx looks at the domain name in the request, but since you're using an IP there isn'tSo it's serving the default server.

If this is the problem, the solution is to make requests to the server using a domain name, not an IP. If you don't have public DNS set up use your local hosts file for testing. eg this goes into your client hosts file file to shortcut DNS for those domains

```
192.168.1.4 example.com www.example.com example2.com
```

Hosts is here for Unix

```
/etc/hosts
```

For Windows

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Here's the default server I use

```
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return      444; # This means "go away", effectively
}
```

Comment: Literally updated it as you posted, just added my default_server config. I will try hosts, I think you might be on to something :)

Comment: Ok the domains don't seem to be working since I updated the hosts. But if I type in my WAN IP address I can successfully connect to 192.168.1.1:8080

Comment: I think my answer is right, you just need to work through with some problem solving technique.

Comment: Ok I'll look more into it, thanks for now. Btw does my default_server config look ok?

Comment: At first glance yours looks ok. I added my default server config to my answer. I don't do IPv6 right now, so add that line in if you do.